# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to merge two models in a blade. Look at my codes

```
public function history_posts_requests () {
    $reports = Report::latest()->where('status', '=', '1')->first()->get();
    $order_mobiles = OrderMobile::latest()->where('status', '=', '1')->first()->get();
    $allOrders = $reports->merge($order_mobiles)->paginate(50);
    return view('Admin.desktops.history_posts_requests', compact('allOrders'));
}
```

But I get this error.

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.

Comment: `->paginate()` is not a method of `Collection`, which is what you get when you run `->merge()`. You'll have to rethink your approach, or use the `->chunk()` method to simulate pagination.

Comment: @TimLewis he can achieve that by using Paginator class, in this way he will not lose the power of the Paginator class

Comment: Yup; I see your answer. This is just a comment on why he's getting the error, and not an answer. The wording "rethink your approach" encapsulates using the paginator class/logic in a different way.

Comment: @TimLewis got your point, SRP, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use `Paginator` and `LengthAwarePaginator` classes to achieve the pagination:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

public function history_posts_requests () {
    $reports = Report::latest()->where('status', '=', '1')->first()->get();
    $order_mobiles = OrderMobile::latest()->where('status', '=', '1')->first()->get();
    $allOrders = $reports->merge($order_mobiles);

    $totalGroup = count($allOrders);
    $perPage = 10;
    $page = Paginator::resolveCurrentPage('page');

    $allOrders = new LengthAwarePaginator($allOrders->forPage($page, $perPage), $totalGroup, $perPage, $page, [
        'path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
        'pageName' => 'page',
    ]);


    return view('Admin.desktops.history_posts_requests', compact('allOrders'));
}
```